# How to Set Focus of Android App Buttons and Entries to Enable Navigation with Keyboard

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to create an android page where I can navigate between entries and buttons by pressing tab on a bluetooth keyboard.

I am able to set the default focus to the first entry but have been unable to change the focus by pressing tab.

I request the focus for my first entry with the following code.

```
editText.RequestFocus();
```

In the layout axml file, I have tried to enable focus for my other entries and buttons with the following code:

```
android:focusable="true"
android:nextFocusForward="@+id/btnEnter"
```

The request on the entry works correctly, but pressing tab does not change the focust to the next button.

Comment: What’s C# got to do with it? Your first code block isn’t visible (to me anyway). Can you provide a [mcve] please?

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the code block to display correctly. I included the c# tag because of xamarin but I suppose I can just remove it. I can try to recreate a minimal example and will link it once done.